# Using OAuth consent screen on Google Cloud Console without credit card

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wonder if i can use the functionality of that OAuth consent screen set in the Google Cloud Console in my application when I don't have any pricing plan set neither credit card assigned to my account. When I logged to Google Cloud Console I didn't activate the free trial but just created the project. My app status is set to "Testing".

I browsed the internet and the answers I have found were that I cannot use the Google Cloud Platform without assigning credit card to it but I have created the project without it and I wonder if it is legal to use it.

Comment: It is not a question of if it is legal. You will not be able to use features that are not part of the Free Trial. An app that is set to testing gets a warning attached that the users see. You will need to upgrade to a paid plan at some point. My advice, write down the services you need to use including storage and networking bandwidth (which is very limited), and then review what is part of the Free Trial. If you do not plan to upgrade to paid, you might be wasting your time as the cloud vendors offer similar services but not the same identical services.

Comment: But as far as I know I am not even using the Free Trial (since it would require assigning credit card) so how am I able to use that feature? And I use that OAuth in app that has very specific purpose and won't be available for people from outside the company.